# Does .NET 5 prefer .NET Framework to .NET Standard?

Tags: nuget, .net-standard, .net-5

I have a NuGet package (let's call it `B`) that references another NuGet package (let's call it `A`). Package `B` targets .NET Standard 2.0. NuGet Package `A` targets .NET Framework, .NET Standard 2.0, and .NET Standard 2.1.

When `B` is consumed by a .NET 5 application (let's call it `C`), it *always* chooses the .NET Framework version of `A`. This produces

> NU1701 warning: was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Why would .NET 5 choose the .NET Framework version instead of one of the .NET Standard versions? This has to be a bug? It must see the other assemblies there and realize that this wouldn't be a warning?

I know I can force a sensible choice in application `C` by setting the `HintPath` to the exact `lib` location of `A`'s assembly. Can I force proper behavior in Package `B` somehow?

`C` Project file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>anycpu</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="B" Version="1.0.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

`B`'s `NuSpec` file has:

```xml
<dependency id="A" version="2.2.1" />
```

Here's my NuGet package repository for `A`. It has an assembly in each folder. I would like .NET Standard 2.0 to avoid warning.

[image]

Comment: What package target is being choose for "A" and "B" when your application "C" is targeting `.NET Standard 2.0` (or `.NET Standard 2.1`)?

Comment: C is an application targeting .NET 5. B is a class library targeting .NET Standard 2.0. B is dependent on A. A is a class library targeting .NET Framework or .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET Standard 2.1 (all three are in the lib directory).

Comment: add B and A directly to C as nuget reference and look what happens.

Comment: Yes, maybe it would except I'm distributing B and not A. I thought it would be better NuGet style to not distribute or have to specify this to users. I know that I could distribute the A assemblies in B package. That's the only thing that I know will work.

Comment: net5 prefers first other netcoreapp TFMs, then netstandard, and netfx last (if the project has AssetTargetFallback set). The fact that your scenario selects a netfx asset means that something different to what you described in the question is happening. A [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is the only way I'll be able to help figure out what's going on. NuGet does each package's asset selection independently, so B's TFM doesn't matter when selecting A's assets

Comment: it makes no difference if C is your test application to test your lib B or a customer using the lib B. You can add it to documentation that customers also have to reference lib A when they use your lib B.